# How to revoke delete in influx db

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-python

I have used delete and deleted values unknowingly, can anyone please tell me how to revoke delete command in influx db. I am using latest version of influxdb.

eg: delete from 'aaa' where name='abcd'

Please help me on this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to restore deleted data except if you have made a backup:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/administration/backup_and_restore/